# no data from rtabmap_ros rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get rtabmap_ros working and it looks like it should be, but I get no map, points or anything from the rtabmap node.  I'm using a xtion camera(working can see PointCloud2), tf from the bot(also working), and depthimage_to_laserscan(working can see scan in rviz).  When I look in rqt_graph everything looks to be hooked up correctly. I'm running Indigo on ubuntu 14.10.
rtabmap section of my .launch :

```
      <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_laserScan" type="bool" value="true"/>

      <remap from="odom" to="/odom_tf"/>
      <remap from="scan" to="/kinect_scan"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

      <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>

      <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
      <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="false"/>
      <param name="Kp/MaxDepth" type="string" value="4.0"/>
      <param name="LccIcp/Type" type="string" value="2"/>
      <param name="LccIcp2/CorrespondenceRatio" type="string" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="LccBow/MinInliers" type="string" value="3"/>
      <param name="LccBow/InlierDistance" type="string" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate" type="string" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr" type="string" value="700"/>
      <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity" type="string" value="0.45"/>
</node>
    <node name="map_assembler" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="map_assembler" output="screen">
        <param name="occupancy_grid" type="bool" value="true"/>
    </node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203452/no-data-from-rtabmap_ros-rtabmap/) by [ocularb0b](https://answers.ros.org/users/21351/ocularb0b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch looks good. If all inputs are correctly connected, the "/rtabmap/mapData" msg should be published at 1 Hz:

```
$ rostopic hz /rtabmap/mapData
```

Are you setting "depth_registration:=true" when launching OpenNI2? Make sure all inputs are published:

```
 $ rostopic hz /odom_tf
 $ rostopic hz /kinect_scan
 $ rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_rect_color
 $ rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/image_raw
 $ rostopic hz /camera/rgb/camera_info
```

Otherwise, can you post the terminal output with "--udebug" as argument?

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ocularb0b](https://answers.ros.org/users/21351/ocularb0b/) on 2015-02-21**:
Thanks for the reply. I've found where I went wrong and need to fix my tf tree.